# Accessing sent email in Google Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I am using a Google Script to send an email and look for any responses to it (there should only be one response, but that is not really relevant here). In theory, I can use search, label, and the `ReplyTo:` option in `GmailApp.sendEmail` to keep track of things. However, I am running into a couple of overlapping issues/concerns because:

- I am sending the same email every week, so search is finicky
- Scripts/Gmail doesn't seem to update quickly enough to find the email it just sent

I want to use the unique Id that Gmail gives every email, but since the `GmailApp.sendEmail` method returns a `GmailApp` object rather than a `GmailMessage` object this doesn't seem possible.

So, how do I programmatically track an email that I have programattically sent?

Below is the code I am using. Open to changes in workflow and methodology, but would prefer to keep this in Google Apps Script.

```
function trigger(minutes){
ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkForEmail")
.timeBased()
.after(100*60*minutes)
.create()
};

function sendEmail(){
//send the email
    GmailApp.sendEmail("name@gmail.com","Subject","Body",{replyTo: "myname+modifier@gmail.com"});
    //get the Id of the email that was just sent
    var emailId GmailApp.search("replyTo:name+modifier@gmail.com",0,1)[0].getMessages()[0];
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("emailId", emailId);
    //set a trigger to check later
    trigger(45)
    };

function checkForEmail(){
var emailId = ScriptProperties.getProperty("emailId");
var email = GmailApp.getMessageById(emailId);
var count = email.getThread().getMessageCount();
var command = "checkForEmail"
if (count == 1){
//set trigger to check again
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(command)
trigger(5)
}
if (count == 2){
//do stuff with the new email: alert me, download attachments, etc.
var attachments = email.getThread().getAttachments()
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(command);
}
else {
//something is weird, let me know
var body = "there was an error with checking an email ("+emailId+")."
GmailApp.sendEmail("myname@gmail.com","Error",body);
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(command);
};
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making a draft, then sending it.

```
var message = GmailApp.createDraft("name@gmail.com","Subject","Body",{replyTo: "myname+modifier@gmail.com"}).send();
```

Answer (score 1):

For the issue of search Gmail, have available the following [Gmail search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) operators, operators `after:` `before:` can help you.

To get the ID of the email sent, I do not know how to get it easily. A proof of concept that comes to mind and that you can adapt and test, is something like:

```
   ...
   GmailApp.sendEmail("name@gmail.com","Subject","Body",{replyTo: "myname+modifier@gmail.com"});
   do {
     /* The search should be as accurate as you can */
     threads = GmailApp.search('replyTo:name+modifier@gmail.com is:sent before:2013/08/27 after:2013/08/27 subject:"Subject"', 0, 1);
   } while(!threads.length);
   ...
```

Besides making all necessary validations (e.g. set a timeout to avoid an infinite loop), will have to check that this does not give problems, e.g. `Script invoked too many times for this user per second` or the like.

Another option may be to set another trigger to find the ID of the mail sent. These are just some ideas.