# How can I get the reply from a email sent?

Tags: google-apps-script

In my code I send an email to a specific email, but I want to store the reply that may come into a cell in the spreadsheet. 
My current idea is to setup a trigger that would run every 2 hours that could check for a reply, but I have no current way to pull out a reply from the message box.

Is there a way that I can do it, or would I have to make a random "code" at the beggining of my subject on my email, so that I could parse my inbox until I have a reply? (I'm not even sure if that's possible"

Comment: Unfortunately there's no `getSent...()` in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app). Someone proposed [retrieving sent mails via searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470622/accessing-sent-email-in-google-apps-script) but I'm not sure if it's working.

Comment: @SangbokLee Thank you, this was the solution I will prbly use!

Answer (score 1):

You can read your inbox using 'GmailApp'. Please see the documentation below -
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

You may look for Subject Line to fetch the email response. Store the fetched data in a variable which can then be passed to spreadsheet using setValue().